# Is there a way to generate SMILES from ChemDraw files?

Tags: computational-chemistry

I have a set of ChemDraw .cdx files, and I would like to extract smiles strings from it.
Can Open Babel do that or maybe the rdkit in Python? Any other suggestions?

Comment: It appears OpenBabel can do this. I haven't looked in the menu for the specifics, but this [web server](http://www.cheminfo.org/Chemistry/Cheminformatics/FormatConverter/index.html) hosts a version of OpenBabel and it is able to convert from cdx to SMILES.

Comment: ChemDraw can do it itself. Is there any special reason why you cannot use it in this case, so that we can better understand what you need?

Comment: If you're looking for a programming lib, here are docs on Indigo: https://lifescience.opensource.epam.com/indigo/api/index.html#reading-sdf-rdf-cml-multiline-smiles-files-cdx-binary

Comment: You can use our web tools: https://eln.chemotion.net/chemscanner. Click on "Scan Files" then "Scan for molecules", then select all the .cdx files that you want to read. After the results are finished, you can click on "Export" and choose "Excel"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course openbabel can do this (at least with release 3.1.0 from [here](https://github.com/openbabel/openbabel/releases)).  To rewrite a file here and then, the GUI on top of the program on top may suffice for you.  However, you would skip *a lot* of the program's functionality if not trying to interact from the command line: for one, the conversion basically follows the pattern of

```
obabel -icdx input.cdx -osmi -O output.smi
```

which actually may be faster than clicking in an interface. For the other, that openbabel offers multiple interfaces to automate file transformations programmatically, i.e. to interact with programming languages like Python and C.  See the *current*  [documentation](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Command-line_tools/babel.html) rather than the a bit outdated on the project's [senior page](http://openbabel.org/wiki/Main_Page).

*Note 1:* ChemDraw offers a structure to SMILES string conversion, too.  Be aware that a `.cdx` file may contain much more information, than a SMILES string may retain.  Seeking for a text-only representation of the molecular structure, axial chirality (P/M) is an example where a SMILES string is less suitable than, for example, an [InChI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Chemical_Identifier) string.

*Note 2:* Openbabel aims to interconvert chemical formats; on occasion with a visual output like `.svg`, or `.png`.  RDKit has a stronger emphasis on computing with the molecules (a.k.a. cheminformatics) as required while interacting e.g., with large sets of data and databases.  There is some overlap of the two programs, and «the trick» is rather to recognize where the two are *complementary* to each other.